# Mybatis IF TEST is asking for getter when parameter is a long

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm running an app with spring + mybatis, and I have the following mapper method:

```
List<Lot> selectAvailableForAuction(Long auctionId);
```

And the XML method is the following:

```
<select id="selectAvailableForAuction" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="Long">
        SELECT <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
        FROM lot
        WHERE
            id NOT IN (
                SELECT lot_id
                FROM auction_lots
                <if test="auctionId != null">
                    WHERE auction_id != #{auctionId}
                </if>
        )
</select>
```

As you can see, the parameter is a Long, and when I'm testing auctionId to check if the value is not null, it returns the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'auctionId' in 'class java.lang.Long'
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.Reflector.getGetInvoker(Reflector.java:419)
...
```

But, if I remove that  it will catch the auctionId perfectly. Looks like test looks for a property in the parameter received. I was looking for it but I didn't find how to test the parameter of the mybatis function itself.

Any idea?

Comment: Try `parameterType="long"`or `parameterType="java.lang.Long"`

Comment: do the same, as you can see in the exception, its ooking for property auctionId in 'class java.lang.Long'

Comment: How is your method annotated or are you using the sessionTemplate to call the xml ?